# Can't serve React + Spring application

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Recently tried deploying my Spring + React app to Heroku but I'm having issues.. What I did: Built the React app, copied the contents of the `/build` directory into `src/main/resource/static` folder of Spring. Then when I opened up `localhost:8080` in my browser, I got the Spring Security default login page. I logged in with an user I had from before and when I went to `localhost:8080` again, my react app loaded just fine.

So then I added this `.antMatchers( "/", "/api/test", "/api/me", "/api/register").permitAll()` to my code, in order to remove the login page from my front end, and when I opened `localhost:8080` now, I get a blank page. But when I log in, the React page again loads fine. I tried the following: putting the react app files into the `/templates` folder, no luck. I tried creating a `/webapp` folder and putting the files in there, no luck. I tried adding `server.servlet.context-path=/` to my application.properties, no luck. I tried creating a redirect controller as so:

```
@Controller
public class RedirectController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getHomePage() {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

Also no luck. I tried changing my Security setup to this: `.antMatchers( "/**", "/api/test", "/api/me", "/api/register").permitAll()` and that actually worked, but then the problem was that all my endpoints were exposed, which is a big no-no.

Also I just noticed that my index.html file is getting served properly, but it is not loading and javascript or any other React file.. What is going on??

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow.. Okay I found the solution, Spring Security was actually blocking access to all my static content except my `index.html`. All that needs to be done is add the `/static/**` in here: `.antMatchers( "/", "/static/**", "/api/test", "/api/me", "/api/register").permitAll()` to let everyone access the static folder. Will probably need to do the same for any other static file that you have like images which aren't in the `/static/` folder.